# Convince manager, to switch from EF db first to code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, management

I really hate dealing with DB first, it is honestly the bane of my existence.
How can I convince my manager that, although the work to switch is a lot. It will be worth it.

Comment: "although the work to switch is a lot. It will be worth it" -> Are you sure this is true?

Comment: @Caleth in the long run

Comment: Consider: It may be cheaper to replace *you* with someone more familiar with DB first, than change the code

Comment: @JSB can you prove that to us? If so, please present your case.

Comment: Also, are you sure your manager cares about the long run?

Comment: @Caleth They can replace me sure, but the system we are currently using is over a decade out of date. No one would prefer this over a new fresh implementation

Comment: How can I convince you to stop using EF? It's horrible

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer I would if I could lol

Comment: @JSB If that's your honest opinion; then why would you ever try to convince your manager to use EF code first? You've just argued against your own assertion  that EF Code First is the way to go.

Comment: I actually found out today that some1 is working on moving to code first :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a burning hatred for DB first. I can't find any benefit to using it in a new project. Code first is clearly superior, unless you're a DBA who struggles with code syntax (at which point I'm wondering what you're doing as a software developer).

Actually, I've always been an even bigger fan of model first (where you create the UML, which generates both the db and the classes for you). But they removed that option from EF so there's no point in bringing it up further.

---

However, I think you're wrong here.

> I really hate dealing with DB first, it is honestly the bane of my existence.

While it's important for a company to not pester its employees, that doesn't mean they need to cater to their whims.

As harsh as it sounds, your opinion doesn't matter all that much to the company, unless it is asked for. Based on your question, the company has already decided to go with db first.

Secondly, you're glossing over a very important step: the decision lies with your manager. Thinking that you can force them to agree with you if you just explain yourself in the right way is **not** a realistic expectation.

There may be other factors at play here, which you're unaware of. Maybe the entire company was trained in DB first, and it would be too costly to have to retrain them. Maybe all the documentation, or coding standards, are built from a database-oriented approach. Maybe most of your company's work is DB related, and most developers are DBA's with side responsibilities.

Whatever the reason, you don't get to decide what the company does. If you did, you'd be the manager who gets to make the decision.

> although the work to switch is a lot. It will be worth it.

One of the most common programmer's fallacies is thinking that *things would be so much better if you built it again from scratch*.

We've all been there. Each and every one of us thinks that at some point. But 9 times out of 10, that is not actually correct.

When you think about building something from scratch, you inherently think about how **you** would like to build it. And that's part of the reason why you like this idea: you get to do things your way. (This can be subconscious, by the way. I'm not accusing you of anything.)

Furthermore, you're likely also glossing over the many corrections that have been made to the business logic since its inception. Not all of them are easily corrected, nor implemented. The perfect soltuion you're envisaging often omits any rare or seemingly uninportant flaws.
For example, I've written simple CSV parsers before, because I couldn't be bothered figuring out how to use a complicated library. **To me**, that was an improvement to the development. But not to others:

- Eventually, fringe cases will be encountered which I never planned for. Existing tools are complex exactly because there are so many fringe cases to cover for.
- While I understand my own parser, others don't. They would prefer reading the documentation of a known tool (or possibly already rely on past experience), as opposed to figuring out my coding style (or documentation style - but how often do we really write documentation for quick and dirty fixes?)

Caleth hits the nail on the head in the comments:

> Consider: It may be cheaper to replace you with someone more familiar with DB first, than change the code – Caleth

If you argue to your manager that DB first doesn't fit well; while the company has been working with DB first successfully for a considerable amount of time, your manager is more liable to conclude that you simply don't fit the company.

**That being said**, I suggest that you talk to your manager about getting a chance to prove the ins and outs of code first. Do this for a **new** project, because that doesn't require you to rewrite the existing code (which is something no one wants to do).

If you genuinely think that EF code first will be better for the company, then your proof of concept will prove that; without you needing to talk the manager into agreeing with something he doesn't agree with.

The key thing you need to change is your expectation. Your *words* are not what need to convince the manager. The *proven concept* should. Your words should only get you a foot in the door to showcase the concept.

Comment: "One of the most common programmer's fallacies is thinking that things would be so much better if you built it again from scratch." -- Yep.